# Is there any IDE for jekyll static site generator?

Tags: jekyll

Is there any IDE for easy development of jekyll sites. which supports Jekyll site generation along with sass compilation.

Comment: Try https://www.JekyllPad.com , it's a wysiwyg online editor for Jekyll integrated with github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution, 'WebStorm' is the tool i'm looking for. It very much integrates with jekyll.

Comment: This is false. WebStorm (and all JetBrains IDEs) flag Jekyll preambles as syntax errors.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) with the [sublime-jekyll](https://github.com/23maverick23/sublime-jekyll) plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from already mentioned Sublime Text, Atom and WebStorm there is also [Brackets](http://brackets.io/). It has quite good [Git](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git) support as well as [Emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet) and [Jekyll](https://github.com/ajsb85/alexsalas.brackets-jekyll). And it is basically aimed to web developers, it is lighter than WebStorm and more web oriented out-of-the-box comparing to Sublime (it has hex color preview for example). So I would suggest to have a look at it as well .

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but https://atom.io is another superb option. Its powered by GitHub

Comment: These off-topic questions shouldn't really be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Netlify CMS](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms), [Prose](https://github.com/prose/prose), [Jekyll Admin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin).

If you want to use an editor with add-ons, I would recommend [Atom](https://atom.io/), a GitHub-made editor like VS Code. People may say Microsoft owns GitHub so why don't you just use the most popular editor VS Code instead. Well, for some languages at some stages, Atom is just way more superior. For example, when it comes to Jekyll static site development for GitHub Pages, Atom is the way to go.

Currently, VS Code's [Jekyll Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ginfuru.vscode-jekyll-snippets) and [Jekyll Syntax Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ginfuru.ginfuru-vscode-jekyll-syntax) have 22k and 30k installs respectively, while Atom's [markdown-writer](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-writer) and [jekyll](https://atom.io/packages/jekyll) have 793k and 27k installs respectively.

However, to directly answer your question of what "IDE" to use, there is no IDE for that. But there are a number of visual frameworks for that. To name a few: [Netlify CMS](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms), [Prose](https://github.com/prose/prose), [Jekyll Admin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin), etc.

You may find this repo very useful: [Awesome Jekyll Editors](https://github.com/planetjekyll/awesome-jekyll-editors).